# Bootstrap resizing and auto-collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently building the website for my brand new creation and - since I've never been such a CSS guru - I need your lights!

- There is a central screenshot (with the editor inside). When the window is at full size, the screenshot appears fine and centered as it's supposed to be. When I start reducing the width of the window, the image seems as if it's moving to the right. Would it be possible to keep it where it initially is, and resize it when the window resizes?
- On resizing, the `navbar` menu collapses and a toggle button (mobile-style) is created in its place. Is there any way to disable this? Or, at least, not trigger at that stage but at a smaller width (while the `navbar-brand` is still fitting)?

**That's the core HTML section:**

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
                    <span class="sr-only" style="color:black;">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" width="40">&nbsp;&nbsp;Peppermint</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Documentation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://sites.fastspring.com/insili/product/peppermint" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Buy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mailto:info@insili.co.uk?subject=Peppermint Support Request"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Support</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="row-fluid" style="text-align:center;">
                <img src="images/screenshot2.png" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**And here's the live page:** http://www.osxpeppermint.com

---

Thanks a lot!

Comment: disable collapsing by removing the collapse class from the nav. and the toggle button.

Comment: Navbar collapse point is defined by `@grid-float-breakpoint`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image is larger than the containing div so it jumps outside. Simplest solution is to add the `img-responsive` to the image:

```
<img src="images/screenshot2.png" class="img-responsive">
```

If you want the nav bar to collapse at a different screen width, you will need a custom download of the Bootstrap library. Go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and change the `@grid-float-breakpoint` value from it's default of `@screen-sm-min` to whatever width you require.

Comment: Awesome. (Omg, how can I possibly have missed that?!) Thanks a lot! ;-)

Comment: As a side note, you should wrap the image in a `col-*` class. See the Bootstrap docs for full info. Class hierarchy in Bootstrap is `container` -> `row` -> `col` -> `content`.

Comment: You mean like `<div class='col-xs-12'><img src="images/screenshot2.png" class="img-responsive"></div>`? As for the main navbar, do you know of any way that I could make it NOT collapse the right menus, or make them collapse at a smaller width? (I mean there is still space left, to the... left, and they collapse)

Comment: Yeah, that would work. As for nav bar, that's a different question! But there doesn't seem to be much room on my screen when it collapses?

Comment: Added a little info on the nav bar!